# IndexError : list index out of range , deep_learning week 4, part 2

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, deep-learning

I ran this code

## GRADED FUNCTION: L_layer_model

def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 4000, print_cost=True):
"""
Implements a L-layer neural network: [LINEAR->RELU]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SIGMOID.

```
Arguments:
X -- input data, of shape (n_x, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector (containing 1 if cat, 0 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
layers_dims -- list containing the input size and each layer size, of length (number of layers + 1).
learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
print_cost -- if True, it prints the cost every 100 steps

Returns:
parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
"""

np.random.seed(1)
costs = []                         # keep track of cost

# Parameters initialization. (≈ 1 line of code)
### START CODE HERE ###
parameters = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Loop (gradient descent)
for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation: [LINEAR -> RELU]*(L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    AL, caches = L_model_forward(X, parameters)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Compute cost.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Backward propagation.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    grads = L_model_backward(AL, Y, caches)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Update parameters.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
            
    # Print the cost every 100 training example
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
        print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
        costs.append(cost)
        
# plot the cost
plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
plt.show()

return parameters, costs
```

followed by
#the code below can not be edited, it is provided in the exercise
parameters, costs = L_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims, num_iterations = 1, print_cost = False)

print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))

L_layer_model_test(L_layer_model)

And I got this error

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 parameters, costs = L_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims, num_iterations = 1, print_cost = False)
2
----> 3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
4
5 L_layer_model_test(L_layer_model)

IndexError: list index out of range

I have tried changing
def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 4000, *print_cost=False):* but it did not help.

```
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: L_layer_model

def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost = False): #lr was 0.009
"""
Implements a L-layer neural network: [LINEAR->RELU]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SIGMOID.

Arguments:
X -- data, numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if cat, 1 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
layers_dims -- list containing the input size and each layer size, of length (number of layers + 1).
learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
print_cost -- if True, it prints the cost every 100 steps

Returns:
parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
"""

np.random.seed(1)
costs = []                         # keep track of cost

# Parameters initialization. (≈ 1 line of code)
### START CODE HERE ###
parameters = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Loop (gradient descent)
for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation: [LINEAR -> RELU]*(L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    AL, caches = L_model_forward(X, parameters)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Compute cost.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Backward propagation.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    grads = L_model_backward(AL, Y, caches)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Update parameters.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
            
    # Print the cost every 100 training example
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
        print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))
    if i % 100 == 0 or i == num_iterations:
        costs.append(cost)
        
# plot the cost
plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.xlabel('iterations (per hundreds)')
plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
plt.show()

return parameters, costs
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).